# JQuery code selects only one element instead of multiple ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

#### The problem:

I execute this script on the *My Saves* page of Google Images but it selects only one element.

According to the [JQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

> Note: most jQuery methods that return a jQuery object also loop through the set of elements in the jQuery collection — a process known as implicit iteration. When this occurs, it is often unnecessary to explicitly iterate with the .each() method:

Which means that my code should work on all the elements which have the specified class. But unfortunately, it is carrying out all of the work only on the first element:

```
$('.col-cv-select').click();
```

I have also tried using explicit iteration with the `.each()` method but the browser console throws an error when I use this script:

```
$('.col-cv-select').each(function (index, element) { element.click(); });
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).each is not a function(…)

I am sure that the page uses JQuery because the first code works quite well, but only selects one element.

#### Reproducing the problem:

- I think you need to be logged in to Google before proceeding.
- Go to *Google* and search for 'unicorns' (or anything you prefer).
- Click on the *Images* tab.
- Select any image. Click on *Save* in the Pop-up.
- Repeat the above step with another image.
- Next visit the [*My Saves*](https://www.google.co.in/save/) page.
- Fire up your browser console and try the codes above.

#### Test Environment:

- Opera 37.0.2178.43 - Stable (Since it's based on Chromium, hopefully, using Chrome will yield similar behavior)
- Windows 8.1 Pro

---

Hope you can help me out :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem to use jQuery. At least for Chrome, `$` is a developer tools function, it is not accessible in page, but can be used from console.

Comment: @AudriusLubys I do not have much experience regarding web development.. was just trying this out coz the page didn't have a select all option... could you please help me with that? Btw, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @AudriusLubys Thank you for the info as well, cheers :)

Comment: I have that page and right above code but i seem that there is a no loaded any jquery.....it's show me error ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

My Saves.htm (line 706, col 1)
16:0:53.544 CSI/tbsd_
16:0:53.545 CSI/_tbnd

Comment: @ParthChavda browser?

Comment: Chrome @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Comment: @ParthChavda Did you use the code in the console or using "javascript:" on the address bar? Chrome and Opera are based on the same Chromium project so they must be similar in behavior.. Weird...

Comment: no i  didn't,i have used your code after save page on my local desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because the `$` variable is defined doesn't mean that jQuery is loaded on the page.

When you run `$('.col-cv-select')` on that page you're actually running `document.querySelector('.col-cv-select')` which by design only returns one element.

The reason you're seeing the TypeError about `$(...).each` not being a function is because the return value of the first function is a DOM node, not a jQuery object.

You can inject the jQuery library into the page by running this code in the developer console: (Taken and adapted from [this page](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet))

```
(function() {
    // more or less stolen form jquery core and adapted by paul irish
    function getScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            done = false;
        // Attach handlers for all browsers
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState ||
                    this.readyState == 'loaded' ||
                    this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;

                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
            }
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
    }

    getScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js');
})();
```

Once you execute that code, the `$` variable will be aliased to `jQuery` and you'll be able to use its `.each` method and everything else that comes with it.

Just remember that once you reload the page the jQuery library will be unloaded, and to load it again you'll need to re-run the code above.

Comment: Fantastic... Well I had the misconception that wherever you see `$`, there must be `JQuery`. And your code just worked like a charm. Now I can tag all my photos no problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import jquery into your chrome browser before testing

use the following block of code, before calling your test code

```js
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type.
jQuery.noConflict();
```